# How to get XXhr completed date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please help me to get following output using pl sql.

```
date    hours   sum (has to be derived when querying out.)
1/1/2014    3   3
1/2/2014    2   5
1/3/2014    4   9
1/4/2014    5   14
1/5/2014    6   20
1/6/2014    2   22
1/7/2014    4   26
**1/8/2014  5   31**
1/9/2014    6   7  (previous day remainder 1 + 6)
1/10/2014   4   11
1/11/2014   8   19
1/12/2014   4   23
1/13/2014   5   28
**1/14/2014 8   36**
1/15/2014   3   9 (previous day remainder 6 + 3)
1/16/2014   4   13
1/17/2014   7   20
1/18/2014   3   23
1/19/2014   6   29
**1/20/2014 2   31**
```

Desired output is as follows.

```
1/8/2014
1/14/2014
1/20/2014
```

Looking forward your quick help.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I am planing to implement a rating process. select query would be more preferable.

Comment: why you are using 30 as dead end while calculating sum but a day is of 24 hours only ??

Comment: this hours represent the hours worked on the particular date and target is to rate the user every 30 hrs worked.

Comment: thats okay but why 30 as last limit instead of 24???

Comment: this 30 is to rate based on the worked hours. its more like every 30hrs worked.

Comment: The running sum is pretty easy: `sum(hours) over (order by date)` applying the limit to it is a bit tricky. This has been asked before but I can't find it right now.

Comment: you could check the below the full demo code in answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is complete demo code for your desired output.

```
create  table dumt (tdate date,hours number);

insert all 
into dumt values('01-jan-2014',3)
into dumt values('2/jan/2014',2)
into dumt values('3/jan/2014',4)
into dumt values('4/jan/2014',5)
into dumt values('5/jan/2014',6)
into dumt values('6/jan/2014',2)
into dumt values('7/jan/2014',4)
into dumt values('8/jan/2014',5)
into dumt values('9/jan/2014',6)
into dumt values('10/jan/2014',4)
into dumt values('11/jan/2014',8)
into dumt values('12/jan/2014',4)
into dumt values('13/jan/2014',5)
into dumt values('14/jan/2014',8)
into dumt values('15/jan/2014',3)
into dumt values('16/jan/2014',4)
into dumt values('17/jan/2014',7)
into dumt values('18/jan/2014',3)
into dumt values('19/jan/2014',6)
into dumt values('20/jan/2014',2)
select * from dual;

commit;

select tdate 
from 
   (
    select tDATE,
    case when lag(the_sum) over (order by the_sum)>30 then 
    mod(lag(the_sum) over (order by the_sum),30)+hours 
    else the_sum end as tsp
    from (
            select tDATE,HOURS,
                  (sum(HOURS) over (order by tDATE)) the_sum 
            from dumt
         ) 
    )
    where tsp>=30;
```

Comment: @user3494938 yuppp it has to as its tested and verified work =30 not mentioned in question ..any way i made there in code too ....

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  min(dt) keep (dense_rank last order by dt desc)
from (
       select
         dt,
         trunc(sum(hours) over (order by dt) / 30) bucket
       from
         tq84_hours
)
where bucket != 0
group by bucket;
```

Working example @ [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac92b/1)